# Unexpected result using opencv3 grabcut function in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I was trying to use the `cv2.grabcut` function with python 3.5 - 
I'm using `cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK` as initiation method, but the results seems weird, and the output mask is not what I was expecting.

`import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#
img  = np.zeros((200,200, 3), 'uint8')
mask = np.zeros((200,200),    'uint8')
cv2.circle(img,  (100,100), 50, (255,255,255), -1);
cv2.circle(mask, (100,100),  5,  1,          -1)
#
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
out_mask, out_bgdModel, out_fgdModel = cv2.grabCut(img, mask, None, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
#
print('opencv', cv2.version) # opencv 3.1.0
#
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,3)
ax[0].imshow(img)
ax[1].imshow(mask)
ax2.imshow(out_mask)
plt.show()`

[image: Example]

Despite the mask initiated to the center of the given circle, it does not capture the full shape but sticks to the original mask shape. Increasing the number of iterations didn't help.

p.s I used this as an exmpale, I'm getting similar results with real images.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to initiate the mask as grabcut enums.
The following fix works.

```
mask = np.full((200,200),cv2.GC_PR_BGD,np.uint8)
cv2.circle(mask, (100,100),  5,  int(cv2.GC_PR_FGD),  -1)

out_mask, _, _ = cv2.grabCut(img, mask, None, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
```